# When OS using hard disk as additional disk space?

Tags: performance, operating-system

Is it correct that an operating system will be using my hard drive space if all active programs will use all RAM space? Which will lead to performance issue (all programs will be work slower because read info from disk is slower than from RAM)

Comment: You are about to learn about concept of "memory paging": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging

Comment: No. A program to run has to be in main memory. And not in secondary storage (hard disk). Read about paging and memory mangement.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it correct that an operating system will be using my hard drive space if all active programs will use all RAM space?

No. The operating system uses one or more paging files to support virtual memory. In a virtual memory system all process memory is mapped to secondary storage. It uses hard drive space even when there is available memory.

> Which will lead to performance issue (all programs will be work slower because read info from disk is slower than from RAM)

If a page of memory has been paged out and has to be retrieved from disk (a page fault), it is a slow process.